# Changing org wide defaults generates an error

Tags: force.com, managed-package

I'm changing the OWD of an object from a managed package from public read/write to public read only. When I click save, I'm getting the error below.  I've done this a few times today, and the error persists. Why is this failing? I know that some locking is involved, but would appreciate some general reasons for failure. Also, is there a fix, aside from just waiting?

> Sharing Locked    The sharing calculation you requested can't be
>   processed right now, because it interferes with another operation
>   already in progress. Please try again later.
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.

Comment: Have you changed / added a sharing rule or such which is already calculating in the background? There is no fix other than waiting until the sharing operation completes either way.

Comment: I checked and that wasn't causing it. is there anything else that may have done it?

Comment: any updates on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from waiting, you could plan a maintenance window for changing the org wide defaults as suggested in the help docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193818&language=en_US):

> **Description**
>
> The purpose of this article is to discuss best practices when making
>   organization-wide sharing changes.  These changes require a
>   recalculation of all record access levels in your organization and can
>   cause adverse effects such as:
>
> Contention Lock errors ("The record you are trying to edit is
>   temporarily unavailable").
>
> Group Membership Lock errors ("Group Membership Locked").
>
> Negative Performance Impacts on your organization.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> When making an org-wide sharing change, it's always best to plan and
>   prepare prior to making these changes.  The specific changes to do
>   this for are:
>
> Org-Wide Default change (***i.e. Changing default access levels from
>   Private to Public Read/Write***).
>
> Large-scale Role Hierarchy modifications.
>
> Creation of multiple sharing rules.
>
> Large-scale Public Groups maintenance (adding/removing members,
>   deleting groups, etc).
>
> For all customers, we recommend that the following are done:
>
> Test the change in a full data Sandbox to ensure the change behaves as
>   expected.
>
> Plan a maintenance window during off-peak hours (w/ low user
>   activity), such as at night, a weekend, or holiday.
>
> For our enterprise customers with very-large organizations, we
>   recommend the following (in addition to the above):
>
> Plan maintenance windows during a weekend, holiday, or period of
>   extended low user activity.
>
> Log a Case with salesforce.com Support to evaluate the changes that
>   are planned to understand overall impact to your org and instance. 
>   This may involve seeking an escalation to the Tier3 team.
>
> Review the following white papers for information on sharing related
>   features and design concepts that can assist in streamlining your
>   maintenance activities:

To better understand what causes the locks take a look at the [Record Locking Cheat Sheet](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/record_locking_cheatsheet.pdf) here.